# GCM notification is not displayed

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working on PUSH Notification.I am using the following code while receiving messages form GCM :

```
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.e(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Message is received but is not displayed as notification.I don't know what  i am missing here .Please help me to fix the issue .

**Log:**

```
 03-07 16:50:21.617  32412-32678/com.almabay.almachat E/MyGcmListenerService﹕ From: 20130254292
03-07 16:50:21.618  32412-32678/com.almabay.almachat E/MyGcmListenerService﹕ Message: Hi Deepak this is is notification from GCM server. 07.03.2016 16:20:52
```

Comment: Is there single notification displaying in your notification bar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply .Nothing is displayed in the Notification Bar.As you can see my code ,i am checking my messages from GCM in the LOG.Please check the edited code for the Log.

Comment: Is it playing ringtone when message is received? i think it is creating issue with rington, can you simply show message and do not do any extra when message received.

Comment: Yes it is playing ringtone but is not displaying notification.

Comment: I have added code in answer which is working fine in my application, hope you can compare and check what went wrong at your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public void notify (int id, Notification notification)

Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

```
public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        int mNotificationId = new Random().nextInt(5000);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
//                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);
    }
```

Hope this will give idea to understand how notification works in android.